# How to make batch file that will swap typed characters (A=T to T=A)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a simple batch file where you can type in the letters for dna bases (A, T, G, C) and it will change the text that you type into the opposite base pairs. Please help me make the code.

Examples:

```
A=T 
T=A 
C=G 
G=C
```

These are all the changes I want the batch file to make. I want the typing to be within the batch file.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. We're here to help you, not do your work for you. Also, please provide more detail. If you absolutely do not know where to start, type `if /?` into your command prompt and see if that helps.

Comment: Why am I so tempted to tag this question `helix-dna` when I know that would be very, very wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

most obvious solution (quite straight forward):

```
set x=ATATATCCGCATCGATCGAA
set x=%x:A=x%
set x=%x:T=A%
set x=%x:x=T%
set x=%x:G=x%
set x=%x:C=G%
set x=%x:x=C%
echo %x%
```

replace "A"s with "x", replace "T"s with "A", replace "x"s with "T". Same for "G"-"C".